# Mat-select loaded from Angular observable in cypress e2e test only loads some times

Tags: angular, asynchronous, cypress, mat-select

I have a test that uses a Mat-Select click event looking for some data (bolded line in code). The test only works sometimes. The data for the select is coming from an Observable/Async pipe. The test either works perfectly or the drop down never loads and the test fails. The bolded line fails because the data never shows up. But the test does work sometimes. I tried waiting, but when it fails it times out.

When manually running the app the drop down is always loaded. So I'm thinking it's some sort of async/timing issue but I'm stumped right now, any help is appreciated

Test:

```
  it('visits the root', () => {
    cy.visit('/');
  });
  it('clicks the menu button expenses option', () => {
    cy.get('mat-icon').click();
    cy.contains('a', 'expenses').click();
  });
  it('clicks add icon', () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/employees').as(
      'dataGetEmployees'
    );
    cy.contains('control_point').click();
    cy.wait('@dataGetEmployees');
  });
  it('fills in fields', () => {
    cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="employeeid"]').click();
    **cy.contains('Smartypants').click().should('exist', { timeout: 2000 });**
    cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="categoryid"]').click();
    cy.get('mat-option').contains('Travel').click();
    cy.get('input[formcontrolname=description]').type('plane tickets');
    cy.get('input[formcontrolname=amount]').type('129.99');
    cy.get('input[formcontrolname=dateincurred]').type('2022-04-25').click();
  });
  it('clicks the save button', () => {
    cy.get('button').contains('Save').click();
  });
  it('confirms add', () => {
    cy.contains('added!');
  });
});
```

This is the error when it fails:

```
Error:     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `mat-option`, but never found it.
    at Context.eval (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\e2e\expense\expense-add.spec.cy.ts:113:30)
```

I added a click to the cancel button and re-issued a click on the add icon and the test works every time now, still not sure why the original click is failing, but I can live with this solution, thanks everyone:

```
  it('clicks the cancel button', () => {
    cy.get('button').contains('Cancel').click();
  });
  it('confirms cancelled', () => {
    cy.contains('cancelled');
  });
  it('clicks add icon again', () => {
    cy.contains('control_point').click();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since observable is asynchronous, it may need a wait for the options to appear.

Try adding a check on the options list length.

```js
cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="employeeid"]').click();   // open the list
cy.get('mat-option').should('have.length', 5)                 // wait for options
cy.contains('Smartypants').click()
```

The `mat-option` elements come and go from the DOM each time the user opens/selects from a list, so there will only ever be one set of `mat-option` present after a `mat-select` click.

Comment: This made no difference, I believe the problem stems from the api call never being satisfied to load the Observable, as the select is there just there aren't any options being loaded

Comment: That looks like a problem in the app - you have an intercept in the test above, is that the data request?

Comment: See the update, cancelling and re-entering the form seems to work every time.

Comment: Perhaps cancel is clearing the observable? Presume you don't get this bother when using the app outside of Cypress?

Comment: App works fine manually and the Observable is getting cleared, but I'm at a loss why the first call only works sometimes, I'm using Angular 14.0.2 so maybe some timing incompatibility with Cypress still??

Comment: I'd have to see the app to figure out what's going on, but it seems like you have a resolution now?

Answer (score 0):

If your mat-select inside of the form, for the first step you need to get the form.

```
it('fills in fields', () => {    
cy.get('form').within((form) => {
cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="employeeid"]').click();
**cy.contains('Smartypants').click().should('exist', { timeout: 2000 
});**
cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="categoryid"]').click();
cy.get('mat-option').contains('Travel').click();
cy.get('input[formcontrolname=description]').type('plane tickets');
cy.get('input[formcontrolname=amount]').type('129.99');
cy.get('input[formcontrolname=dateincurred]').type('2022-04-25').click();
})
});
```

Comment: This made no difference, I believe the problem stems from the api call never being satisfied to load the Observable, as the select is there just not populated

Answer (score 0):

I removed the wait and re-entered the form and everything is working,the final code is now:

```
describe('expense add test', () => {
  it('visits the root', () => {
    cy.visit('/');
  });
  it('clicks the menu button expenses option', () => {
    cy.get('mat-icon').click();
    cy.contains('a', 'expenses').click();
  });
  it('clicks add icon', () => {
    cy.contains('control_point').click();
  });
  // hack for timing bug, need to re-enter form
  it('clicks the cancel button', () => {
    cy.get('button').contains('Cancel').click();
  });
  it('clicks add icon again', () => {
    cy.contains('control_point').click();
  });
  it('fills in fields', () => {
    cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="employeeid"]').click(); // open the list
    cy.get('mat-option').should('have.length.gt', 0); // wait for options
    cy.contains('Smartypants').click();
    cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="categoryid"]').click();
    cy.get('mat-option').contains('Travel').click();
    cy.get('input[formcontrolname=description]').type('plane tickets');
    cy.get('input[formcontrolname=amount]').type('129.99');
    cy.get('input[formcontrolname=dateincurred]').type('2022-04-25').click();
  });
  it('clicks the save button', () => {
    cy.get('button').contains('Save').click();
  });
  it('confirms add', () => {
    cy.contains('added!');
  });
});
```